# How to perform automatic Update on Multiple Servers while performing commit on svn?

Tags: svn, commit

I want to perform automatic update on multiple servers automatically as soon as i commit changes on my code

More specifically

I have multiple instances of my code and i want to update them all as soon i commit changes on my code

Project is based on PHP

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to perform automatic update on multiple servers automatically as soon as i commit changes on my code

Is code on your servers inside Working copies or not? Your actions depends from this condition

- If you servers are WCs of repo, your task is start "svn up" **for each server** from repository's post-commit hook (ssh + cd + svn up...)
- If your servers aren't WCs and you have access to filesystems on these servers, you use `svn export` + rm old + copy new in (also) post-commit hook

Answer (score 0):

Use some cron or other scheduling utility on each instance to regularly poll the SVN and update automatically if there have been changes. Or install a post-commit hook on the server which would start a remote update script on every client instance (but this is of course more complex).

Note that all these instances should have a read-only copy of the code. Else, an update could need manual merges to be done in order to succeed.

Comment: ok thanks, but is it possible to run svn update on another server by using terminal of my server

Comment: No, you need to do the update on the machine where the update must be done. Using ssh or ternet could be the solution. I still fail to see why you need such a synchronization, though. Just let everyone update when he wants (or needs) to.

Comment: I am working on a web app, now this application can be installed on any server, so i just want to update my code on each instance of my app , as soon as i commit changes in it